# BIRT data set prints same data for every item

Tags: birt

I have a BIRT report for Maximo with two scripted data sets.   The main data set for purchase requests and the sub data set for purchase request lines.   The problem is that the sub data set works fine for a single purchase request and prints the correct data for any give PR, but if you run the report for multiple PR's, the pr lines for the first PR are printed out for every PR.

So what I am getting is something like this.

PR 10

Line 1

Line 2

PR 20

Line 1

Line 2

When PR 20 should have 10 lines, it only gives me two and those two are the same lines as PR 10.   I've set the report to print out the SQL that is being created by the data set by populating a global variable called mySQL and printing that on the report.   The SQL looks fine and I can cut and paste it into my SQL editor and get the correct results, but that is not what is printing out on the report.   I've checked table bindings, I've tried to null out the data set in the script and force it to repopulate but that has no effect. I've created a new data set, but the new data set does the same thing.

Has anyone run into this before?  Any ideas at all on what to check?  Or how do I go about clearing out the dataset for each PR so that the PRLINE dataset will be clean for each PR?

This is the open script for the dataset.

```
lineDataSet = MXReportDataSetProvider.create(this.getDataSource().getName(),         this.getName());
lineDataSet.open();

var sqlText = new String();

// Add query to sqlText variable.
sqlText = "select orderqty, orderunit, itemnum, description, unitcost, linecost, prnum,    prlinenum, refwo, assetnum, location, project,tasknum, siteid from maximo.prline_vw "
+ " where prnum = '" + rows[0]["prnum"].replace(/'/g,"''") + "'"
+ " and siteid = '" + rows[0]["siteid"] + "'"
//+ " where prnum = '" + row._outer["prnum"] + "'"
//+ " and siteid = '" + row._outer["siteid"] + "'"
// Include the Maximo where clause
//+ " and " + params["where"]
;

lineDataSet.setQuery(sqlText);

mySQL = sqlText;
```

And this is the fetch script.

```
if (!lineDataSet.fetch())
return (false);

// Add a line for each output column
// The specific get method should match the data type of the output column.
row["prlinenum"] = lineDataSet.getString("prlinenum");  
row["orderqty"] = lineDataSet.getFloat("orderqty");
row["orderunit"] = lineDataSet.getString("orderunit");  
row["unitcost"] = lineDataSet.getFloat("unitcost");
row["linecost"] = lineDataSet.getFloat("linecost");
row["prnum"] = lineDataSet.getString("prnum");
row["itemnum"] = lineDataSet.getString("itemnum");
row["refwo"] = lineDataSet.getString("refwo");
row["siteid"] = lineDataSet.getString("siteid");
row["description"] = lineDataSet.getString("description");
row["project"] = lineDataSet.getString("project");
row["tasknum"] = lineDataSet.getString("tasknum");
row["assetnum"] = lineDataSet.getString("assetnum");
row["location"] = lineDataSet.getString("location");


return (true);
```

Comment: Did you try to disable cache for Dataset through Properties->Dataset->Advanced->Needs cache for data-engine =  false ?

Comment: I am unable to find that property SiMemon.   I'm on BIRT 3.7.1   Is that property available on my version?

Comment: You are right, it is not available in BIRT 3.7.1 . Why don't you upgrade to newer version?

Comment: These reports are for Maximo 7.5, so until IBM upgrades the BIRT used in Maximo I'm stuck on the version we are on.

Comment: Okay..i was not aware of that stuff

Answer (score 1):

Without having read the details:

A common reason for this is that your scripted data set uses a variable.
That is, the results depend on the value of the variable, but BIRT does not know this.
**BIRTs data set result caching works depending on the DS parameters.**
If you add the global variable as a DS parameter to the DS, then the caching mechanisms knows that the results depend on it and you're done.
If not, BIRT thinks that the results are always the same.

Comment: Hi hvb,     Can you be a smidge more specific?   Are you saying that I need to add the variable for the data set as a global variable?  If so, do I just need to declare the variable as a global in the initialize of the report?  Or do I need to move the entire line  toolDataSet = MXReportDataSetProvider.create(this.getDataSource().getName(), this.getName());    Out into the report initialize?      The only variable the scripted data set is using is rows[0]["wonum"]    Which prints out on the report fine?  Even though it isn't working in the dataset apparently.

Comment: Your detail DataSet (for PR lines) is depending on the current row of the master DataSet (for PR). To be more precise, on the Java object "lineDataSet". Thus you must either disable caching or create a DS Parameter "ds"for the detail DS, use *that* in the detail DS events with this.getInputParameterValue("ds") and bind it to the lineDataSet object in the layout.

Comment: You're way over my head hvb.   :)     I could not find a way to disable caching in BIRT 3.7.1        And as for the rest.  I don't know what a DS Parameter is?  Is that different than a regular report parameter?   And when you say bind it to the lineDataSet object in the layout, are you saying to just have a hidden field that sets "ds" to the work order number (or whatever I am keying off of)?

Comment: You should really look at the BIRT tutorials about DataSet parameters and binding :-)

Answer (score 0):

This appears to only be happening when I view the report from the Eclipse BIRT developer.  If I upload the report to the working environment and test it, it appears to work fine.   So it must have something to do with the way the scripted data sources are cached and how the developer handles that?